# What are the inverses of these common vector calculus differential operators?

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding some vector calculus equations.

If
$$ f(r) = \nabla_r g(r)$$
then
$$ \Delta g(r) = \int f(r) \cdot \mathrm{d} r$$

and

if
$$ f(r) = \frac{\mathrm{d} g(r)}{\mathrm{d} V_r} $$
then
$$ \Delta g(r) = \int f(r) \, \mathrm{d} V_r $$

But the inverse for other operators is hard.

How would I rewrite these equations as $g = T[f ]$ for some operator $T$?

$$ f(r) = \nabla \times g(r) $$

$$ f(r) = \nabla \cdot g(r) $$

And for the Jacobian which doesn't have a standard notation but I like to use $\nabla \otimes$ for.

$$ f(r) = \nabla \otimes g(r) $$

And for the Laplacian operators

$$ f(r) = \nabla \times \nabla \times g(r)$$

$$ f(r) = \nabla \cdot \nabla g(r) $$

$$ f(r) = \nabla \nabla \cdot g(r) $$

Comment: The divergence and curl are both non-injective: you can only "solve" $\nabla \cdot g = f$ up to a divergence free shift, and you can only "solve" $\nabla \times g = f$ up to a gradient.

Comment: @Ian the derivative isn't injective either?  If $\frac{\mathrm{d} f(t)}{\mathrm{d} t} = g(t) $ then $\frac{\mathrm{d}f(t) + c}{\mathrm{d} t} = g(t)$ for any $c$. So, I'm totally happy to have a solution like $g(r)  = T[f] + \nabla \phi$ or $g(r)  = T[f] + \nabla \times \phi$.

Comment: Yes, the derivative is not injective, but its kernel is simple: it's just the constants. The divergence free functions are a much more complicated class. Anyway, what you seem to be going for is the so-called Helmholtz decomposition. I don't know a simple formula for it, even in 3D.

Comment: @Ian Yes Helmholtz decomposition works for the curl operator $\nabla \times$. Do you know if there is something similar for the divergence operator $\nabla \cdot$ ?

Comment: They work simultaneously: the Helmholtz decomposition splits a vector field into a divergence free part (i.e. a curl) and a gradient (i.e. a curl free part).

Comment: @Ian given a function $F = \nabla \times A$ you can use the Helmholtz decomposition theorem to obtain A from F. I don't think you can do the same thing for $F = \nabla \cdot B$ using the theorem. Looking into the matter I think you have to use a generalization of the technique using this weird thing I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_potential

Comment: Given a vector field $F$ the Helmholtz decomposition writes it as a gradient plus a curl. You're right that inverting the divergence is actually another problem.